# SQL How do I find values from a list that are not in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with values in a field called 'code'.

```
ABC
DFG
CDF
```

How would I select all codes that are not in the table from a list I have?
Eg:

```
SELECT * from [my list] where table1.code not in [my list]
```

the list is not in a table.

The list would be something like `"ABC","BBB","TTT"` (As strings)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi the list is not in a table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using SQLite (android app)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT code 
FROM Table1
WHERE code NOT IN ('ABC','CCC','DEF') --values from your list
```

It will result:

```
DFG
CDF
```

If the list is in another table, try this:

```
SELECT code 
FROM Table1
WHERE code NOT IN (SELECT code FROM Table2)
```

**As per your requirement,** try this:

```
SELECT list
FROM Table2
WHERE list NOT IN (SELECT code from table1)
```

It will select the list values that are not in code. 
See an example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24ea75/2)

Comment: Thanks, but i want the values from the list that is not in the table, not the other way around.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you are putting into helping me. But the list is not in a table (as mentioned in my post) they are "strings" that i can use in the sql.

Comment: And how are you passing that string to sql?

Comment: I will be putting it into the query manually. So however it needs to be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49730/discussion-between-raging-bull-and-fuzz)

Comment: @Fuzz: Did my answer get you what you are looking for? If yes, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others in future to find the correct answer.

Comment: No it did not answer my question as I do not have the values in a table.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use common table expressions?

```
WITH temp(code) AS (VALUES('ABC'),('BBB'),('TTT'),(ETC...))
SELECT temp.code FROM temp WHERE temp.code NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT table1.code FROM table1);
```

This would allow you to create a temporary table defined with your list of strings within the VALUES statement.  Then use standard SQL to select values NOT IN your table1.code column.

Comment: The syntax on the CTE part is a bit incorrect. Here it is with correct syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c4034b/3

Comment: @plasmaTonic thanks - I've updated the VALUES syntax.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

The question key point need to set `"ABC","BBB","TTT"` source data trun to a table.

that table will look like

```
|---+
|val|
|---+
|ABC|
|BBB|
|TTT|
```

Sqlite didn't support `sqlite` function. so that will be a little hard to `sqlite` your list to be a table.

You can use a `CTE Recursive` to make like `sqlite` function

1. You need to use `replace` function to remove `"` double quotes from your 
   source data.
2. There are two column in the CTE

   - `val` column carry your List data
   - `rest` column to remember current `splite` string

You will get a table from `CTE` like this.

```
|---+
|val|
|---+
|ABC|
|BBB|
|TTT|
```

Then you can compare the data with `table1`.

---

**Not IN**

```
WITH RECURSIVE split(val, rest) AS (
    SELECT '',  replace('"ABC","BBB","TTT"','"','') || ',' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  
         substr(rest, 0, instr(rest, ',')),
         substr(rest, instr(rest, ',')+1)
    FROM split
    WHERE rest <> '')
SELECT * from (
  SELECT val
  FROM split 
  WHERE val <> ''
) t where t.val not IN (
  select t1.code 
  from table1 t1
)
```

*sqlfiddle:https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5adeba5dfcc2fks5jgd7ernq*

**Outut Result:**

```
+---+
|val|
+---+
|BBB|
|TTT|
```

---

If you want to show it in a line,use `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

```
WITH RECURSIVE split(val, rest) AS (
    SELECT '',  replace('"ABC","BBB","TTT"','"','') || ',' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  
         substr(rest, 0, instr(rest, ',')),
         substr(rest, instr(rest, ',')+1)
    FROM split
    WHERE rest <> '')
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(val,',') val from (
  SELECT val
  FROM split 
  WHERE val <> ''
) t where t.val not IN (
  select t1.code 
  from table1 t1
)
```

**Outut Result:**

```
BBB, TTT
```

*sqlfiddle:https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5adecb92fcc36ks5jgda15yq*

---

Note:That is unreasonable on `SELECT * from [my list] where table1.code not in [my list]`,because This query has no place to find `table1` so you couldn't get `table1.code` column

You can use `not exists` or `JOIN` to make your expect.

*sqlfiddle:https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5adeba5dfcc2fks5jgd7ernq*

Answer (score 0):

Is this solution good, or am I missing something?

```
create table table10 (code varchar(20));

insert into table10 (code) values ('ABC');
insert into table10 (code) values ('DFG');
insert into table10 (code) values ('CDF');

select * from (
  select 'ABC' as x
  union all select 'BBB'
  union all select 'TTT'
) t where t.x not in (select code from table10);
-- returns: BBB
--          TTT
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5cf5a/9).

Comment: This is selecting values from a table that are not in a list. OP wants to select values from a list that are not in a table.

Comment: My bad. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
drop function if exists testcsv
//
create function testcsv(csv varchar(255)) returns varchar(255)
deterministic
begin
    declare pos, found int default 0;
    declare this, notin varchar(255);
    declare continue handler for not found set found = 0;

    set notin = '';
    repeat
        set pos = instr(csv, ',');
        if (pos = 0) then
            set this = trim('"' from csv);
            set csv = '';
        else
            set this = trim('"' from trim(substring(csv, 1, pos-1)));
            set csv = substring(csv, pos+1);
        end if;
        select 1 into found from table1 where code = this;
        if (not found) then
            if (notin = '') then
                set notin = this;
            else
                set notin = concat(notin, ',', this);
            end if;
        end if;
        until csv = ''
    end repeat;
    return (notin);
end
//
select testcsv('"ABC","BBB","TTT","DFG"')
```

Output:

```
BBB, TTT
```