# Select ids from array of numbers that are not in a Table

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the following table data:

```
Students.id
-----------
1
2
3
```

If I want to select ids from a table that are not in an array of numbers, I can do the following:

```
SELECT id FROM Students
WHERE id NOT IN (1, 3, 5);

Result: (2)
```

But I want to do the opposite - **select numbers from an array that are not in a table**. How can I do that?

Here have been my attempts so far:

```
Attempt 1:

SELECT id FROM TABLE(1, 3, 5)
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Students);

RESULT: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
------------------------
Attempt 2:

SELECT (1, 3, 5) FROM dual
WHERE ??? NOT IN (SELECT id from Students); -- not sure what the column name should be

RESULT: Executing the first line alone gives the error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
--------------
Attempt 3:

SELECT TABLE(1,3,5) AS ids FROM dual
WHERE ids NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Students);

RESULT: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Desired results (from my examples): (5)

**Note**: I found [this related question, but alas it is also unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400811/sql-how-do-i-find-values-from-a-list-that-are-not-in-a-table). Like Fuzz, my array of numbers are not stored in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a collection type:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9709b/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE NumbersList IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

and then you can use it in a query:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id
FROM   students
WHERE  id NOT MEMBER OF NumbersList( 1, 3, 5 )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9709b/2/0)**:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  2 |
```

Or, to reverse it and have the numbers in the collection not in the table, you can use a table collection expression (`TABLE(:your_collection)`):

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE( NumbersList( 1, 3, 5 ) )
WHERE  COLUMN_VALUE NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM students )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9709b/2/1)**:

```
| COLUMN_VALUE |
|--------------|
|            5 |
```

You can even pass the collection as a bind variable ([examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264) passing it from PL/SQL and from a java array).

Comment: Query 2 was closest to what I was looking for - a way to keep all the values in an array form (so it is easily extendable)

Answer (score 1):

You may try anti joining a CTE containing your ID numbers to the `Students` table:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 FROM dual
)

SELECT t1.id
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN Students t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Your requirement is fairly easy to come by, using a join or a few other methods, provided that your data is in a proper table.  If you have a long term need for this, then I recommend getting your data into tables.

We could also write the above query using `EXISTS`, which might have better performance:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM cte t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Students t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
```

Comment: I think the array may be change

Comment: Is anti-joining better or worse performance-wise than the "WHERE NOT IN ([sub query])"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the table build in proper way eg: using union  instead of an array  :

```
  select id from (
  select 1 id  from dual 
  union 
  select 3  from dual 
  union 
  select 5  from dual ) t 
  where t.id NOT IN (
  SELECT id FROM Student
  )
```